# Custom UITableViewCell reverse indent when cell is editing

Tags: uitableview, indentation, reverse

I have customized a UITableViewCell class in Swift.I defined a textField in this class and added constraints to it.

```
    class DBCell: UITableViewCell {
       var textField:UITextField?
        required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            textLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
        required override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
            super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
            textLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        }
    }
    class DBEditCell: DBCell{
      required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      uper.init(coder: aDecoder)
     fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    required init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
      super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
      if textField == nil
     {
     textField=UITextField(frame: CGRectZero)
     }

    textField?.textAlignment=NSTextAlignment.Left
    textField?.clearButtonMode=UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing
    textField?.enabled=true

    self.shouldIndentWhileEditing=false
    textField?.delegate=self
    contentView.addSubview(textField!)

    textLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    //Add constraints to textField
    let hBinds=NSDictionary(objectsAndKeys:textLabel,"textLabel",textField!,"textField")
    textField?.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[textLabel]-[textField]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: hBinds))
    let vBinds=NSDictionary(objectsAndKeys:textField!,"textField")
    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[textField]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: vBinds))

}
}
```

When I created custom cell from tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) and set editing in UITableView,it looks well.
[image: Good]
But when I selected a custom cell,that cell outdented and looks ugly.
[image: Bad]
Why custom cell moved left and upper? How can I resolved this problem? Any advice should be appreciated.

Today I have added constraint to DBCell :

```
let vBinds=NSDictionary(objectsAndKeys:textLabel,"textLabel")
contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[textLabel]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: vBinds))
```

And I found that the cell contain center when is editing,but the cell still move to left.I have tried to add horizontal constraint to textLabel like this:

```
contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[textLabel]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: hBinds))
```

And it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved!
I have modified my code to this:

```
class DBCell: UITableViewCell {
   var textField:UITextField?
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    required override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
}
class DBEditCell: DBCell{
  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
  uper.init(coder: aDecoder)
 fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
required init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
  super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
  if textField == nil
 {
 textField=UITextField(frame: CGRectZero)
 }

textField?.textAlignment=NSTextAlignment.Left
textField?.clearButtonMode=UITextFieldViewMode.WhileEditing
textField?.enabled=true
self.shouldIndentWhileEditing=false
textField?.delegate=self
contentView.addSubview(textField!)
textField?.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
let hBinds=NSDictionary(objectsAndKeys:textField!,"textField")
contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[textField]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: hBinds))
let vBinds=NSDictionary(objectsAndKeys:textField!,"textField")
contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[textField]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: vBinds))
```

Now I don't set any constraints to textLabel,only set constraints to textField,and I get the right alignment textField.
[image]